# Youtube get videos and playlist accounts

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm creating a media house mock app and am wondering whether there is a way I can get video playlists from a certain account which is not mine for example if a user has a page that is [http://www.youtube.com/someuser](http://youtube.com/someuser) is it possible to get all the videos and playlist from that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use youtube video feeds([Youtube RSS Video Feeds](http://www.youtube.com/t/rss_feeds))

Make following requests using GET and read the xml data returned.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{{username}}/playlists - For playlists
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{{username}}/uploads - For uploads
```

Orderby parameter can be used to change order of videos.